# Join or marge between two tables with different dateframe

Tags: r

i'm new in R , and i'm trying to join between two tables. the shared filed between the two tables is the date but when i'm importing the data i received him with deferent structure.

First Table:
[image]

Second Table:
[image]

actually what i need is to join the data by operation system and remove Linux like inner join in sql with condition on the operation system.  Thanks

Comment: Do not post your data as an image, please learn how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610)

Answer (score 0):

Say that your first dataset is called `df1` and the second one `df2`, you can join the two by calling:

```
merge(df1, df2, by = "operatingSystem")
```

You can specify the kinds of join by using `all = T`, `all.x = T`, or `all.y = T`.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit lazy to reproduce your example but I will give it a go as is

First, in your second table, you need to convert the *date* column to an actual date

You can do this with easily with `lubridate`

Assuming `df1` and `df2` for the first and second table respectively

```
library(lubridate)
df2$date <- ymd(df2$date)  #ymd function assumes `year` then `month` then `day` when converting
```

Then you can use the `dplyr`'s `inner_join` to perform the desired join

> from [stat545](http://stat545.com/bit001_dplyr-cheatsheet.html#semi_joinsuperheroes-publishers)
>
> inner_join(x, y): Return all rows from x where there are matching values in y, and all columns from x and y. If there are multiple matches between x and y, all combination of the matches are returned.

```
library(dplyr)
semi_join(df1, df2, by = c("date", "operatingSystem")
```

This will keep all rows in `df1` that have a match in `df2` - Linux stays out, and also keep the columns `newusers` and will keep `df2%users` and rename into `users.1`.

Note:You might need to convert `df1$date` to `dttm` object with `lubridate::date(df1$date)`